# How to get current directory of main python file?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `argparse` in a python file "hello.py"

I am executing this file using

```
python hello.py -infile "ex1.txt" -op1 "2"  ....
```

How to get which directory "hello.py" file is located? I know that `os.path.dirname()` can be used for `infile`, but how to know the same thing "hello.py"?

Comment: import os
print(os.getcwd())

Answer (score 0):

try `__file__` for full file name :-)

Comment: `__file__` is usually **not** the full pathname, though.

Comment: In which cases it isn't?

I tried before posting, putting `print __file__` in `main` body  (Python 2.7.6)

Comment: In scripts started from the Python command line. `__file__` is equal to `sys.argv[0]` in that case; the same path used on the command line. If you started the script with a relative pathname, so is `__file__` a relative pathname. The correct way to use `__file__` is to make it absolute first (with `os.path.absname(__file__)`).

Comment: import os

print(os.getcwd())